# GeoServer cuts parts of my raster images out and fill other ones with the black color

Tags: geoserver

I have some historical maps that I would like to serve by a GeoServer.

These historical maps are GeoTIFF files that use EPSG:4326 and they have the alpha band.

I've opened them in my QGIS and they are connected correctly.

[image]

However when I serve them inside a GeoServer, with default parameters, for some reason, that I don't know, parts of my rasters are cut out and other ones are filled with the black color, in both QGIS visualization by WMS and GeoServer layer preview.

- QGIS visualization by WMS:

[image]

- GeoServer layer preview:

[image]

I don't understand why this event is happening, because the first and second pictures above illustrate the same GeoTIFF files, where the first picture they are showed by QGIS and the second one they are served by GeoServer using WMS.

What is wrong?

**EDIT 1:** Ian Turton's questions.

- How did you add them to GeoServer?

  I have a GeoServer 2.16.2 inside a [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/geoserver/) with a volume inside my host machine where the rasters are. Then, I've created a Mosaic with default options (I did not change anything) that points to the volume with my rasters.
- Is it a mosaic or individual rasters?

  Mosaic. I added a new Store > ImageMosaic and I published the layer with default options.
- What projection did you set?

  The projection that I did set to my rasters is EPSG:4326.
- What projection is the map you are viewing?

  My background image is OSM and its default projection is EPSG:3857.
- Does the log file have any interesting messages for you?

  No, it does not, unfortunately. The layer preview of my raster inside GeoServer is equals to the QGIS visualization by WMS.

**EDIT 2:** Layer information inside GeoServer.

Inside [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/rmmariano/9e63769d908938901c224e5af05b3ae4) I've added print-screens to illustrate the layer information inside GeoServer.

Comment: How did you add them to GeoServer? is it a mosaic or individual rasters?, what projection did you set? what projection is the map you are viewing? Does the log file have any interesting messages for you?

Comment: Thank you for your questions. I've answered them inside the original question.

Comment: If it works in the GeoServer preview but not in your client then the issue is probably with the client - please add more details about that

Comment: No, it does not work in the GeoServer preview, unfortunately. The third image illustrates that the GeoServer preview shows the rasters erroneously. I've added a Gist with pictures to illustrate the layer settings. Is there another information you would like that I add here? Thank you.